# How to response a custom string for a JSP Servelet Request

Tags: jsp, servlets

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
....
....
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/output.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

What I need is not to redirect into another JSP page at the end of `doPost`. I have a string (plane text), I need to response it as for the Servlet request. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  response.setContentType("text/html");
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  out.append("Your string goes here");
  out.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/message.jsp").forward(request, response);
response.getWriter().println(output); // output is the custom string
```

can find more info from http://devzone.skillfusion.com/ajaxArticle8.php